# A lag function honors how data are sorted, but crosses a group, and this I do not want: I must be mistunderstanding how window and lag functions work

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm doing a covid data extraction and I would like to compare for each French department (`dep` and `lib_dep`: code and name), the rate of people who are hospitalized a day (`hosp`) on the number cases known 5 days before.

For that, I'm running this script, from a dataset ready in a  variable named `synthese`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec

val w:WindowSpec = Window.orderBy("dep", "date");
var cas_relatif_hospitalisation = lag("cas", 5).over(w);

synthese = synthese.withColumn("cas_relatif_hospitalisation",
    cas_relatif_hospitalisation)

synthese.select("date", "lib_dep", "populationDepartementale", "tx_incid", "cas", 
   "cas_relatif_hospitalisation", "hosp", "rea").show(1000, true)
```

Here is a part of the results I'm receiving:

| date | lib_dep | populationDepartementale | tx_incid | cas | cas_relatif_hospitalisation | hosp | rea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | Ain | 647634 | 1578.03806957859 | 10220.0 | 6809.0 | 106 | 15 |
| 2022-01-03 | Ain | 647634 | 1879.58079320501 | 12173.0 | 7852.0 | 109 | 15 |
| 2022-01-04 | Ain | 647634 | 2104.10149858057 | 13627.0 | 8977.0 | 97 | 10 |
| 2022-01-05 | Ain | 647634 | 2241.24940064388 | 14515.0 | 9864.0 | 112 | 10 |
| 2022-01-06 | Ain | 647634 | 2332.12320478572 | 15104.0 | 9935.0 | 118 | 11 |
| 2022-01-07 | Ain | 647634 | 2473.83762967022 | 16021.0 | 10220.0 | 116 | 11 |
| 2022-01-08 | Ain | 647634 | 2696.83616077205 | **17466.0** | 12173.0 | 112 | 13 |
| 2022-01-09 | Ain | 647634 | 2743.11025869352 | 17765.0 | 13627.0 | 112 | 13 |
| 2022-01-10 | **Ain** | 647634 | 2800.34401138586 | **18136.0** | 14515.0 | 122 | 13 |
| 2022-01-11 | Ain | 647634 | null | null | 15104.0 | 139 | 13 |
| 2022-01-12 | Ain | 647634 | null | null | 16021.0 | 147 | 13 |
| 2022-01-13 | Ain | 647634 | null | null | **17466.0** | 143 | 11 |
| 2020-03-18 | Aisne | 533316 | null | null | 17765.0 | 41 | 10 |
| 2020-03-19 | **Aisne (!!!)** | 533316 | null | null | **18136.0 (!!!)** | 43 | 15 |
| 2020-03-20 | Aisne | 533316 | null | null | null | 52 | 19 |
| 2020-03-21 | Aisne | 533316 | null | null | null | 61 | 20 |
| 2020-03-22 | Aisne | 533316 | null | null | null | 69 | 21 |

When I see the `cas_relatif_hospitalisation` (D-5 value of `cas`) of 2022-01-13 (YMD) for the *Ain* department, it has the value I'm willing: the content of `cas` column for 2022-01-08.

But when I see the `cas_relatif_hospitalisation` value that comes soon after, as the department has now changed and became *Aisne*, I notice that the D-5 value for (*Aisne*, 2020-03-19) is the one of (*Ain*, 2022-01-10). And it's not what I was expecting...

Yes, spark goes five record back. Following the good order.
But for me, the department was a bound, a frontier that `lag` function shouldn't have crossed, and I was expecting a null value. But it did.

What am I doing wrong, or misunderstanding about `lag` and `window` functions usage?

Comment: You're using a non-partitioned window. You need to partition by department: `Window.partitionBy("lib_dep").orderBy("date")`

Comment: Oups!!! It's ok. Sorry !
Put this as an answer if you want, so that I can accept it, for the 10 points you deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@blackbishop in comments found that

I was using a non-partitioned window.
I needed to partition by department: `Window.partitionBy("lib_dep").orderBy("date")`